# How to iterate through each property of a custom vb.net object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, properties

How can I go through each of the properties in my custom object? It is not a collection object, but is there something like this for non-collection objects?

```
For Each entry as String in myObject
    ' Do stuff here...
Next
```

There are string, integer and boolean properties in my object.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

By using reflection you can do that. In C# it looks like that;

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = myobject.GetType().GetProperties();
```

---

Added a VB.Net translation:

```
Dim info() As PropertyInfo = myobject.GetType().GetProperties()
```

Comment: Where is the value inside each entry?

Comment: There is a method named propertyInfo.GetValue().

Comment: How does this work in the context of a `For Each` loop?

Comment: @tmsimont You would loop through the array propertyInfo ie.  `For Each i in propertyInfo  //Do stuff Next`

Answer (score 45):

You can use **System.Reflection** namespace to query information about the object type.

```
For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In obj.GetType().GetProperties()
   If p.CanRead Then
       Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(obj, Nothing))
   End If
Next
```

Please note that it is not suggested to use this approach instead of collections in your code. Reflection is a performance intensive thing and should be used wisely.

Comment: I had a problem. it's error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 7):

System.Reflection is "heavy-weight", i always implement a lighter method first..

//C#

```
if (item is IEnumerable) {
    foreach (object o in item as IEnumerable) {
            //do function
    }
} else {
    foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p in obj.GetType().GetProperties())      {
        if (p.CanRead) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(obj,  null)); //possible function
        }
    }
}
```

'VB.Net

```
  If TypeOf item Is IEnumerable Then

    For Each o As Object In TryCast(item, IEnumerable)
               'Do Function
     Next
  Else
    For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In obj.GetType().GetProperties()
         If p.CanRead Then
               Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(obj, Nothing))  'possible function
          End If
      Next
  End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection...  With Reflection you can examine every member of a class (a Type), proeprties, methods, contructors, fields, etc..

```
using System.Reflection;

Type type = job.GetType();
    foreach ( MemberInfo memInfo in type.GetMembers() )
       if (memInfo is PropertyInfo)
       {
            // Do Something
       }
```