# Set max length of strings in radgrid / limit string length in radgrid with autogenerate columns

Tags: c#, sql, linq, telerik, sql-view

Is there any way to tell a radgrid to truncate the length of strings in its columns? Im using a radgrid to show data from a sql view which has several (many, many) fields, so I want to use the autogeneratefields="true" rather than setting up all of the gridboundcolumns, and/or doing the truncation in the itemdatabound event or anything like that.

I suppose I could ask it this way also, what would be a good approach to getting data back from a view and have the fields only return the first x number of characters? As I said there are many fields so I don't want to have to code out every column in my dal and do a substring or something like that....

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Rusty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if my question made sense, but in case anyone comes across a similar scenario, I ended up looping through my object's properties and truncated the strings before setting the datasource on the radgrid.

```
public static void SM_Dump_TruncStrings(ref List<myDataType> dump, int maxLength, bool addEllipses)
    {
        foreach (var sm in dump)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] infos = sm.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var info in infos)
            {
                if (info.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    var origValue = info.GetValue(sm, null) as string;
                    if (origValue != null && origValue.Length > maxLength)
                    {
                        var newVal = origValue.Substring(0, maxLength);
                        if (addEllipses)
                            newVal += "...";
                        info.SetValue(sm, newVal, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This approach was taken from here : [How to iterate through each property of a custom vb.net object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314426/how-to-iterate-through-each-property-of-a-custom-vb-net-object)

cheers,

rusty